UITextView transform three dots into ellipsis
When Im typing into UITextField and put three dots in it one by one, the textfield convert them into one symbol-> "..." . Same bahavior with dashes. When Im typing two dashes the field convert them into one long dash. Is it possible to avoid this behavior? I need three dots symbols instead of one symbol.

I think this is because of some autocorrection, did you try to turn of the autocorrection / spellchecking of the UITextField?

You need to turn of SmartDashes on your UITextField... This will turn of this behavior...
You can do this in your InterfaceBuilder, or in Code by
uiTextField.smartDashesType = .no


The docs on smartDashesType say "Use this property to configure whether UIKit converts two hyphens into an en-dash and three hyphens into an em-dash automatically". Where is it documented that this property also controls converting 3 dots to an ellipsis? (And if it's not documented, how did you figure it out?)

I don‘t know, I just tried it in Xcode and it worked… :-)
